# How to check if windows updates are enabled in a remote computer

Tags: c#, windows-update

I want to execute the code below to a remote computer in order to find if windows update is on or off:

```
WUApiLib.AutomaticUpdates auc = new WUApiLib.AutomaticUpdates();
bool active = auc.ServiceEnabled;
```

how can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find this : http://www.daveoncsharp.com/2009/10/enumerating-and-controlling-windows-services-with-csharp/

I think it's what you are looking for.